# Drag html text and that text dropped on svg image

Tags: jquery, html, svg, drag-and-drop

I have an html text list in a ul li format which I want to drop on a svg image. But there is some problem occured when I am doing like this.

My html code structured something like this:

```
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorum Ipsum </li>
        <li>Lorum Ipsum 2</li>
        <li><img src="..." /></li>
    </ul>

    <svg><image .../> <rect>...</rect> <circle>....</circle> </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to drag this Lorum Ipsum text on an image tag which is nested in the svg tag.

How can I resolve this problem? Also we need a text in html tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul><li id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Lorum Ipsum</li></ul>

<svg  ><image id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)"
        ondragover="allowDrop(event)"/> <rect>...</rect> <circle>....</circle> </svg>

<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }

    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }

    function drop(ev) {
        debugger;
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");

        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));

    }
</script>
```

Comment: It should not be worked properly. Also when i implement this code the li tag dragged but not seems on the top of an image.